# Android -- How to get complete article from the RSS feeds?

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing, rss

Well I am learning Android RSS Feeds parsing, and I have a question. Consider I am using Goal.com RSS feed and displaying on my Android phone.

[Goal.com RSS Feed : http://www.goal.com/en-us/feeds/news?fmt=rss](http://www.goal.com/en-us/feeds/news?fmt=rss)

But as you can see from the Rss feeds, they are only the headlines of the article containing 2 - 3 lines of the description. I was wondering is there any way I can get the complete article from it after parsing the feeds. Any pointers to guide me would be helpful . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the RSS feed doesn't contain the full article, there isn't an easy way to get it.  You can look at the `link` tag for each item to find it on the web and then do some screen scraping, but that gets ugly fast.

Answer (score 1):

@Clifton is correct. Even by this nature we can save our posts from autoposter plugins. Besides you can find the common pattern of your target web page where contents resides. You can etract that area of content programmatically.